# how to show the datepicker method call from different class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating custom datepicker in my view controller class. then i need datepicker in another view controller class. so i want to create common datepicker that any view controller class can use and show the date. So how can i use it. Please share the code.

I use this code:

```
 actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Date" delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                 destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [actionSheet setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor ]];
    [actionSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 470, 375, 200)];
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake ( 0, 10, 300, 100)];
    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet addSubview:datePicker];
    UIToolbar *toolbarPicker = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolbarPicker.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    // toolbarPicker.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [toolbarPicker sizeToFit];
    NSMutableArray *itemsBar = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //calls DoneClicked


    UIBarButtonItem *btnDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneClicked)];
    [itemsBar addObject:btnDone];
    [toolbarPicker setItems:itemsBar animated:YES];
    [actionSheet addSubview:toolbarPicker];
    [self.view addSubview:actionSheet];
}

-(IBAction)dateChanged{
        self.dateEntry.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[datePicker date]];
}


-(IBAction)doneClicked{
    [actionSheet removeFromSuperview];
    self.dateEntry.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create custom class of `UIView/NSObject`, Add your logic over there & then implement delegation design pattern to manage it.

Let me know if you need anymore clarification for the same.

Comment: Sure, refer this link https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/UIActionSheet-Blocks its a block based Action Sheet where everything is managed you don't need to worry about anything.. If you have any doubt in it then let me know